# Map Marker with InfoBox AddListener Not Working

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Here I am using Map api, I created marker with infobox like this

```
   infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({            
    }); 

    var pushIcon = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:options.position,                                      
    });

    pushIcon.marker = new InfoBox({
    disableAutoPan: true,
    content : '<div id= "markerarraydiv" class="marker apartment category-blue"><div class="mrker-inner"> <img src="'+icon+'" alt=""></div></div>',
    pixelOffset : new google.maps.Size(-20, 0),
    closeBoxURL           : "",
    isHidden              : false,
    pane                  : "floatPane",
    enableEventPropagation: true
     });

    pushIcon.marker.open(map, pushIcon);
```

but here iam unable to make addListener on this marker

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(pushIcon, 'mouseover', function() {
    //alert("mouse over");
        infoWindow.setOptions(options);
        infoWindow.open(map, pushIcon);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(pushIcon, 'click', function() {
        //console.log("clicked"+options.id);
        alert("clicked");

    });
```

I am getting map with my custon markers,but mouseover on marker not working
  The code working fine when creating a marker without using infoBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got answer for this, here i placed one transparent image on marker

```
   var pushIcon = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:options.position,   
    icon:transparentimage                                   
    });
```

and set

```
 pixelOffset : new google.maps.Size(-20, -36) solved my problem
```